# Android Scrollview not expanding vertically

Tags: android, scrollview

Just a random issue with my scrollview in XML below.  I have a dynamic listview that gets built.  The list view could be 3 lists long or more.  My problem is the scrollview below is only expanding the height up to only one listview.  I need it to go all the way down to the bottom of the screen/tablet.  Any suggestions?

```
  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_cars"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_spinner"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
>


    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_cars"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</ListView>
```

may be this work...

Answer (score 0):

If you need your ListView to go all the way to down, why do you need scrollView? ListView alone Automatically does this. Just take the ListView inside the linear layout. Try the code below

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_cars"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_spinner"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
        </ListView>
           </LinearLayout>
```